# Converting a Tree to an Array

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to convert a BST to an Array.

```
void treeToArr(Node *root, int *ptr, int index)
{
if (root == NULL) {
    return;
}

storeInArray(root->left,ptr,index);
ptr[index++] = root->value;
storeInArray(root->right,ptr,index);
}
```

When running this, I noticed that the index number kept changing, it went from 0 to 1 to 0 to 1 to 2 to 3. I just want it to increase normally [1,2,3,4..]. I'm new to C and i'm unsure why it's doing this.

Note that when I call this function, index is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a pointer to index instead of index itself. That way, index will be modified across all recursive calls.

Comment: Well, it's C, so a pointer, not a reference, but close enough.

Comment: @ShadowRanger A pointer, as in... a nullable reference?

Comment: @ShadowRanger A bit rusty as I have been off C since the 90's.

Answer (score 0):

It's one thing to pass values 'down' in recursive calls. 
You could use a pointer to a single instance of an `int index;` that exists in the top level caller. 
Or, you could return to 'parent nodes' what the child nodes have done with the value.

```
int treeToArr(Node *root, int *ptr, int index)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return index;

    index = storeInArray(root->left, ptr, index);
    ptr[index++] = root->value;
    return storeInArray(root->right, ptr, index);
}
```